# Remove all files in *that* directory except *these* files - dangerous in remote directory?

Tags: bash, rm, sshfs

I'm writing a small bash script for deploying a bunch of files to a specific remote directory. The process is as follows:

1. Mount remote directory (sshfs)
2. Remove everything *except* these few files
3. Copy all the files from the local directory to the remote one.

I suddenly realized that if something went wrong mounting the remote directory, for example if I'd lost my internet connection, this script would remove everything from the directory I'm currently in! Which could easily be disastrous. So - what would the correct procedure be?

Comment: This question is off-topic here as not related to programming but is  for SuperUser where you can discuss system administration tasks. 
Use proper `rsync` tool designed for this specific requirement to synchronize copy files between directory and optionally remote destination through ssh, clering destination directory of all files not in source and synchronizing source to destination.

Comment: I agree with other comments here but also consider writing your cmds to std-output and examining them carefully for bugs. ie. `for f in * ; do echo "/bin/rm $f" ; done > /tmp/deleteListDebug.txt` , or something like that. Good luck.

Comment: Write error checking into your script. If the mount step fails, the script should detect that, and exit (or do something else appropriate). If you use `cd` in the script, you absolutely need to handle the error if the `cd` fails for any reason (and it's usually best to avoid `cd` in scripts, partly for this reason).

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't provide your script I'm going to guess a little bit what it looks like. There might be several points for improvement.

The first and most important point would be to prevent accidental local access by design. So use paths to your mounted files instead of `cd`'ing into a directory that might not exist. Do write:

```bash
rm /mnt/everything_except_these_files
```

If you don't want to use `/mnt` as a mount point, consider creating a temporary directory using `mktemp -d`.

Next, and almost as important: abort your script on error. Writing `set -e` at the top of the script will accomplish that. If your `mount` fails, no other commands will be run.

To navigate around the shortcomings of `set -e` in certain cases, you might also consider `exit`'ing explicitly if an important command failed, like this

```bash
mount ... || exit 1
```

(thanks to tjm3772 for bringing up the issue)

You can test if a directory is actually a mount point using the `mountpoint` command. This will fail on a local directory.

I hope any of these suggestions might help.

Comment: `set -e` is often considered [bad practice](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) because of its inconsistency across shell versions and the number of ways it can produce unintended behavior. A better recommendation is to explicitly test the mount command and exit on failure that way (e.g. `mount <options> || exit 1`).

Comment: @tjm3772 thank you for pointing out. I edited my answer to account for your comment. I have to say I'm not completely convinced. For a sufficiently simple script, `set -e` will work as intended. It's a good point nevertheless and one to keep in mind.